# Deleting columns in a data frame using a list of variable names

Tags: r, subset

I have an automated script that produces a standard formula (i.e., y~x1+x2) and I would like to screen my data out based on those variables.

So far I have gotten this far, but I hit a sticking point where I can't quite figure it out:

```
#Example data
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=2:6, z=3:7, u=4:8)
df
  x y z u
1 1 2 3 4
2 2 3 4 5
3 3 4 5 6
4 4 5 6 7
5 5 6 7 8        
#Example formula
ex_form = "x~y+u"
#Delete the ~ and add a + sign to be consistent
step1 = gsub("~","+", ex_form)
#Remove + signs
step2 = strsplit(step1, "\\+")
#Final list of variables
step3 = unlist(step2)
```

Most solutions I've seen is something along the lines of:

```
#Create list of variables
mylist = c("x", "y", "u")
#Cut data
temp = df[ ,mylist]
temp
  x y u
1 1 2 4
2 2 3 5
3 3 4 6
4 4 5 7
5 5 6 8
```

But this solution doesn't quite fit into the automation...so I need to jump from what I have to that outcome.  Any thoughts?

Note: Tags are my guesses.

Comment: Isn't  `df[,step3]` a solution?

Comment: Use `df[, step2[[1]]]` and you are all set.

Comment: @adiana and Gopala: Yep, it was actually that easy.  For some reason, I thought it had to be within the 'c()" framework.  Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't put your formula between `" "` it will be recognized as such, and can use `all.vars()` to extract variables from it.

```
ex_form = x~y+u #Without quotes it is a formula, check str(ex_form)
df[, all.vars(ex_form)]
#  x y u
#1 1 2 4
#2 2 3 5
#3 3 4 6
#4 4 5 7
#5 5 6 8
```

Comment: `all.vars(as.formula(ex_form))` could also be used if they can't re-assign `ex_form`

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something or does simply doing `temp <- df[,step3]` return exactly what you say you want?